# Python3 How to retrieve specific dates from a dataframe for stock using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to retrieve the Amount from specific dates to see what is the wealth that the stock has given.

From what I have done so far:

INPUT

```
initial_amount = 10000
amount_A = []

for numbers in A['Return_A']:
    amount_A.append(initial_amount * (1 + numbers))

df = pd.DataFrame({'Stock Price A': A['Adj Close'],
                   'Stock Returns A': A['Return_A'],
                   'Amount': amount_A
                  })

df['Amount'] = df['Stock Returns A'].add(1).fillna(1).cumprod()*initial_amount

print(df.head())
```

OUTPUT

```
             Stock Price A  Stock Returns A           Amount
Date                                                   
2018-12-31      161.670441            NaN       10000.000000
2019-01-02      166.490067       0.029811       10298.114228
2019-01-03      164.051193      -0.014649       10147.259607
2019-01-04      169.412827       0.032683       10478.899286
2019-01-07      170.351578       0.005541       10536.965017
```

If you take a look at the "Amount" column, the initial amount is $10,000.

The dates range is from 2018-12-31 to 2019-12-31.

How do I retrieve the values of "Amount" from specific dates such as; for e.g:

5 March 2019, 17 June 2019, 22 September 2019?

I want the output to be like:

```
Date         Amount
2019-01-07 10536.97
```

Please help!

Comment: How about`df[df['Date']=='2019-01-07'][['Date','Amount']]`

Comment: Hi @SCool, it does not seem to be working as it produced a 'key error'

Comment: @SCool, I downloaded some stock information by using 'yfinance', and when I set it into a dataframe, I did not set the 'Dates' as the index; it just worked normally.

Comment: OK. If the dates are the index, then my first comment should be: `df[df.index=='2019-01-07'][['Amount']]`

Comment: @SCool, it worked! thank you so much! By the way, how do I round the 'Amount' column dataframe to nearest dollar? like maybe 0 decimal

Comment: Try this: `df['Amount'] = round(df['Amount'])`. Then print the dataframe and check it. I will post the answer to your first question, and since it worked, could you mark it as an answer? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219859/discussion-between-zoarkado-zenos-and-scool).

Comment: Hi again @SCool, now that I can extract one date from the above code:, is there a way to retrieve several index into a single dataframe? Like '2019-01-07', '2019-04-14', '2019-10-11'?

Comment: I missed the chat invitation, not sure if it's still working. So I'll post here. To get multiple dates, first make a list of dates then use `isin`. For example: `date_list = [ '2019-01-07', '2019-04-14', '2019-10-11']` now use this list: `df[df.index.isin(date_list)][['Amount']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to display your desired output:

```
df[df['Date']=='2019-01-07'][['Date','Amount']]
```

If the date is in your index, try this:

```
df[df.index=='2019-01-07'][['Amount']]
```

To round your numbers to the nearest dollar:

```
df['Amount'] = round(df['Amount'])
```